# jQuery DatePicker ui is failing on IE

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

IE is giving me an undefined NAN when i try to view the calender...

here is my html

```
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ altField: '#outing_suggested_date', minDate: new Date, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", defaultDate: new Date("2010-10-07"), setDate: new Date("2010-10-07") });
```

here is the code i use to generate it

```
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ altField: '#outing_suggested_date', minDate: new Date, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", defaultDate: new Date("<%=@current_object.suggested_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")%>"), setDate: new Date("<%=@current_object.suggested_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")%>") });
```

Any ideas...maybe IE cant handle something, all other browsers are fine

Comment: You've accidentally pasted JS twice instead of HTML and JS. And could you try not to paste it all in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see for the option `minDate` you've used the value `new Date`, change that to `new Date()`. Maybe that already does the trick.

Comment: FYI - IE likes the year included in whatever data is being evaluated by .datepicker. If you only output a mm/dd, it also shows as undefinedNAN in IE.  Event though that works just fine in Chrome and FF

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `/` instead of `-`, and also `yy/mm/dd`.